# How to read .runsettings test parameter in xUnit fixture

Tags: xunit, runsettings

I'm writing **xUnit** unit test cases for a *dotnet core* application which uses *DocumentDB (CosmosDB)* as storage. The unit test are written to execute against the *local cosmos db emulator*. On the Azure DevOps build environment, I've setup the [Azure Cosmos DB CI/CD task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd) which internally creates a container to install the emulator. However, I'm not able to figure out that how the endpoint of emulator can be passed to xUnit fixture?

Is there any way through which xUnit fixture can read the .runsettings test parameters or parameters can be passed via other source?

**Update**

Currently, I implemented the scenario using Environment Variable but still not happy to define the connection string as a environment variable using powershell in build task and read it in through code during unit test execution. I was thinking if there could be another way of achieving it..

Below snapshot shows how the build tasks are configured currently as workaround to achieve the desired:
[image]

And code to read the value as

```
var serviceEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbEmulatorEndpointEnvironmentVariable");
```

Since, UnitTest task provides the option to pass .runsettings/.testsettings with option to override the test run parameters so was thinking it something can be achieved using those options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I implemented the scenario using Environment Variable but still not happy to define the connection string as a environment variable using powershell in build task and read it in through code during unit test execution. I was thinking if there could be another way of achieving it..

Below snapshot shows how the build tasks are configured currently as workaround to achieve the desired:
[image]

And code to read the value as

```
var serviceEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbEmulatorEndpointEnvironmentVariable");
```

Since, UnitTest task provides the option to pass .runsettings/.testsettings with option to override the test run parameters so was thinking it something can be achieved using those options.

Answer (score 9):

This is not supported in xUnit.

See SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458979/whats-an-xunit-runsettings-equivalent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121043/what-is-the-attribute-in-xunit-thats-similar-to-testcontext-in-visual-studio-te), and [this github issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1439) indicating that it is not something that will be supported in xUnit.