Can I change a connection string in xUnit class fixtures?
I've implemented a DatabaseFixture similar to the example in the xUnit docs, which looks like this:
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        Db = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");

        // ... initialize data in the test database ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ... clean up test data from the database ...
    }

    public SqlConnection Db { get; private set; }
}

public class MyDatabaseTests : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    DatabaseFixture fixture;

    public MyDatabaseTests(DatabaseFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    // ... write tests, using fixture.Db to get access to the SQL Server ...
}

But I want to run my tests across multiple environments, in which the database connection string may change. I understand that xUnit does not support parameterized ctors in fixture definitions, but hardcoding a string feels bad. Given that fixtures are initialized very early in the testing lifecycle, how can I change this string based on where the tests are running?

I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977531/how-to-read-runsettings-test-parameter-in-xunit-fixture

Oof, that's rough, but resorting to env vars might be the only recourse here. Thanks

There is solution I can think of - we can borrow idea from ASP.NET project templates and use environment variable (equivalent to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT), but not in order to hold connection strings or other data, just to hold environment that we want to test in.
So, on test host (machine that you will use to run tests on) you need to define environment variable XUNIT_ENVIRONMENT (or pick other name of your choice) and you use it like below in unit test:
public class UnitTest1
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        var environemnt = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("XUNIT_ENVIRONMENT");

        _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environemnt}.json")
            .Build();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {

    }
}

Then you can add appsettings.{env}.json, where env could be local, dev and prod for example, and this could be set in the environment variable.
Of course, this requires adding nuget packages:

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Of course, this is just POC and you can built on top of that your solution.
One thing that comes to my mind is that building configuration in tests' constructor is bad idea - it will build for each test, while it's enough to build it once and then use it in tests' fixtures.
UPDATE
Of course, you can place building configuration in DatabaseFixture class:
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        var environemnt = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("XUNIT_ENVIRONMENT");

        _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environemnt}.json")
            .Build();

        Db = new SqlConnection(_config["MyConnectionString"]);

        // ... initialize data in the test database ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ... clean up test data from the database ...
    }

    //public SqlConnection Db { get; private set; }
}

References:

ConfigurationBuilder Class
JsonConfigurationExtensions.AddJsonFile Method


The class fixture gets instantiated before the unit test gets constructed, though, right? So this configuration setup would hit after the fixture is created. That said, could the env var get retrieved in the construction of the DatabaseFixture in much the same way?
Putting config -> db connection in the unit test ctor would prohibit me from sharing contexts across tests, as xUnit runs the ctor > test for each [Fact]

@Blue Hm this is actually good place to put it. Please see update
